# Bad Event Order?

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I have wxTreeCrtl and wxPropertyGrid.

I handle **wxEVT_PG_CHANGED** for checking when user finishes modifying

and

**wxEVT_COMMAND_TREE_SEL_CHANGED** for checking when user changes selection in tree

Now imagine this situation: 
I modify something in propertyGrid and finish modifying by clicking on some object in tree(different then currently selected). 
Is it correct behavior, that **wxEVT_COMMAND_TREE_SEL_CHANGED** is send before **wxEVT_PG_CHANGED**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known bug. It can be solved by catching first event and manually resend it into message pump (wxPostMessage). It will guarantee message is at bottom of mess. pump and event order will be fixed.